# Tabla mediante consulta de MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi BBDD:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

En la tabla '`users_subjects`' estoy relacionando las tablas '`subjects`' y '`users`'.

Por ejemplo, si introduzco un usuario 'EJEMPLO' con ID = 1 y asignaturas SAT y ICT con los ID 1 y 2, la tabla '`users_subjects`' tendría un aspecto similar al siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pretendo hacer una tabla donde los usuarios que tengan varias asignaturas se muestren en un solo campo. Hasta ahora he conseguido que se muestre solo con los id’s de las asignaturas: (subject_id), de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría tener una tabla donde se muestran los nombres de las asignaturas como la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que debo hacer una relación entre las tablas ‘`subjects`’ y ‘`users_subjects`’. Pero no lo estoy consiguiendo. Alguien me puede echar una mano? Gracias

```
$sql2 = "SELECT us.*,s.subject FROM users_subjects us, subjects s where us.subject_id_fk=s.subject_id";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
```

Aquí tengo mi código:

```
<table class="users">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4"><h2>USUARIOS</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Usuario </th>
        <th> Asignatura </th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rol='profesor'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if ($result->num_rows==0){

    echo 'No hay usuarios';
}else{
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $subjectsList = "";
    $sql2 = " SELECT user_id_fk, GROUP_CONCAT(subject_id_fk SEPARATOR ',') AS subjectList FROM users_subjects WHERE user_id_fk=" . $row["id"] . " GROUP BY user_id_fk;";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);


    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $subjectsList = $row2["subjectList"];
    }

    /*$sql2 = "SELECT us.*,s.subject FROM users_subjects us, subjects s where us.subject_id_fk=s.subject_id";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);*/

        echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$row["username"]."</td>
                  <td>".$subjectsList."</td>
                  </tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es unir las tres tablas y hacer un GROUP BY por nombre e id de usuario y usar GROUP_CONCAT con las materias

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(s.subject) as subjects FROM users_subjects us
JOIN users u ON u.id = us.user_id_fk 
JOIN subjects s ON s.subject_id = us.subject_id_fk 
WHERE u.id = ? 
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
```

Donde `?` es el id que le tienes que pasar. Tal como lo tienes es muy vulnerable a Inyección SQL, deberías usar sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Lo he sustituido dentro de `$sql2` y puesto `'AS subjectList'`, ya me salen los nombres de las asignaturas pero siembre salen los mismos aunque haya diferentes IDs en las tablas

Comment: Vale hacía falta añadir  `$sql2 = " SELECT u.id, u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(s.subject SEPARATOR ',') as subjectList FROM users_subjects us
JOIN users u ON u.id = us.user_id_fk 
JOIN subjects s ON s.subject_id = us.subject_id_fk  WHERE user_id_fk=" . $row["id"] . "
GROUP BY u.id, u.username";`

Comment: Si, eso es porque falta el WHERE. te edito la query. Eso si deberias usar consultas preparadas porque tal como esta ese WHERE es muy vulnerable a intyeccion SQL: Tambien cambiaria el `while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()` por un if puesto que solo vas a recibir un resultado.

Comment: Si, gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de editar mi código. :D